# Why provide vi and vim?

Tags: vim, redhat-enterprise-linux, vi

I think I'm right in saying RedHat and other distributions provide both vi *and* Vim.

Does anyone know what the rationale is behind providing both when presumably if Vim is provided it covers the functionality of vi?

ETA: It's not a symlink, they're different binaries.

```
$ ls -lh /bin/vi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 747K Jul  7  2012 /bin/vi
$ ls -lh /usr/bin/vim
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.9M Jul  7  2012 /usr/bin/vim
```

Comment: has a possible duplicate in StackOverflow. Maybe it answers your question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1159341

Comment: Is it really vi?  I know ubuntu symlinks both /usr/bin/vi and /usr/bin/vim to /etc/alternatives/vim . . .

Comment: `vi` is in the POSIX standard.

Comment: Everyone seems to be ignoring the fact that the OP is not asking about **the difference**, but "what the rationale is behind providing both". In other words, WHY BOTH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old question but it's still true Redhat provides vi removing dependence on /usr (except for ftdetect - probably harmless) and a whole lot of modules that at one time had security issues. Vim is part of vim-enhanced and not installed by default on server builds. It includes scripts in /etc/profile.d to alias vim if not set and the euid > 200. There also are two rc files for each, .virc for vi and .vimrc for vim, leading to a lot of head scratching as to why it works in one place but not the other.

There are other ways to do this but you can see what each is doing two ways:

```
(vi|vim) -V
strace (/usr/bin/vi|/usr/bin/vim) -c q # quit immediately
```

Answer (score 3):

RedHat and its variants/clones tend to provide a /bin/vi that is essentially Vim compiled with the bare minimum of features and fewer library dependencies so it is more likely to be able to run even with a damaged filesystem.  It is also smaller than a "normal" or "huge" version of Vim, which at one time was a consideration even if it does not matter as much now.

Basically it is there as a "fallback" for users and admins that need a text editor and are at least minimally familiar with vi.  For those who want a more powerful editor, they usually have to expressly install "vim-enhanced" or whatever their distribution provides for a "full featured" Vim.

I have seen even tinier versions of `vi` or vi-like editors that are not a stripped down Vim that some of the compact distributions use.  Busybox integrates one.

Answer (score -1):

No you are wrong.

Redhat and all the other distros provide both a `vi` and a `vim` *commands* but they are not separate executables: `vi` is just a symlink to `vim`. This happens on every UNIXy systems because the `vi` command is [part of the standard](https://www2.opengroup.org/ogsys/catalog/c436) and, as such, must be provided by a system if it claims to be UNIX-compliant.

Presumably, at some point, most distros decided to use `vim` instead of the original `vi` (for reasons unknown to me: architecture compatibility? modern features? others?). Which is why you get both `vi` and `vim`.

Comment: I stand corrected: you and me are *partially* wrong. Debian-based distros and Mac OS X have symlinks but Redhat seems to have two binaries. Yes, it sounds silly. You should ask Redhat about that.

Comment: I imagine it's a case of 'if it ain't broke...' - I can't imagine that it costs them more than a negligible amount of effort to provide both of these, so there's no need to risk upsetting whatever weird, unanticipated corner-cases might possibly be affected by a change.

Comment: RHEL 6 has a **vim-minimal** package which provides `/bin/vi` and a **vim-enhanced** package which provides `/usr/bin/vim`.